# next 13 send image from api (create qrcode image in api)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

In api from url params I generate custom qrcode(other app use this qrcodes).
I don't see an option to send a buffer in `NextResponse`.
It is possibly send image from next 13 api?

My code from next 12 api

```
  // <code generate qrcode> 
  const buffer = Buffer.from(clearString, "base64");

  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
  });
  res.end(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It easy,

```
  return new Response(buffer, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
    },
  });
```